# I cant send my image uploaded in React frontend to the backend developed in Django

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have developed a webapp and used the following lines of code to send an image to backend.

```
    const SubmitImage = () => {
        if (!image) return alert('Please select an image first');

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('image', image);

        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000//api/classify-image', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                Navigate('/output', { state: { image: image } });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
    };
```

I am sending the file uploaded as Image and also moving to a new page at the same time.
On the backend side, I am using this to receive the image.

```
class UploadView(APIView):
    # permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, JSONParser)

    @staticmethod
    def post(request):
        Image_predict= request.data.get('Image')

        #loading models
        ResNetModel = ResNetModelConfig.model
        InceptionV3model = InceptionV3modelConfig.model

        # Preprocess the image (this needs to be checked)
        image_raw = Image.open(Image_predict)
        image1 = np.array(image_raw.resize((224, 224)))
        if len(image1.shape) == 2: #code checks if the image is grayscale. If it is, the image is converted to color by duplicating the grayscale channel three times to create an RGB image.
            image1 = np.expand_dims(image1, axis=2)
            image1 = np.concatenate([image1, image1, image1], axis=-1)
        elif len(image1.shape) == 3 and image1.shape[2] == 4: #code checks if the image has an alpha channel. If it does, the alpha channel is removed.
            image1 = image1[:, :, :3]
```

I end up getting a 500 Internal Server Error
or
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek'`
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'`

How do i solve this?

I wanted the code to be able to receive the image and send back a prediction.(which i have not included here in the code)
I am new to backend development so I donot have much clues in what i could do to avoid this.